# Custom Attribues in Frontend showing for wrong product

Tags: magento-1.9, bug

### Steps to reproduce:

**VERSION 1.9.3.2**

Item with custom options... for example

> https://tiptopweddingshop.co.uk/funky-boys-socks-page-boy-ring-bearer-etc.html

In the **backend**, the Custom Options are **correct**:

1. Date / Field
2. Option / Dropdown / with options such as "Groom", "Best Man", etc
3. Text Colour / Dropdown / with options such as "Yellow/Orange", "White, etc

In the **frontend**, the Custom Options are displaying **INcorrectly**:

1. OK
2. Not all options show, repeats the first part of the list
3. Text Colour is showing options from ANOTHER PRODUCT!

#### Notes:

1. Backend shows the custom options and the correct selectable value
2. Data Export shows data is fine and matches the backend above in Note1
3. Have Flushed Cache, Reindexed, etc several times, still not working

### Expected Result:

Custom Options display correctly in frontend

### Actual Result:

- This is ONLY in the frontend, the backend is fine and a data export shows the correct options.
- 2nd Custom Option is not showing all the options and appears to repeat the top half of the list
- 3rd Custom Option is showing the correct option title, but the option values are from a Custom Option FROM ANOTHER PRODUCT!

[image: See screenshot]